# trying to use ActiveRecord with Sinatra, Migration fails question

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

running Sinatra 1.0, I wanted to add a database table to my program. In my Rakefile I have a task

```
task :environment do   
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML::load(File.open('config/database.yml'))["development"])      
end
```

I have a migration task in my namespace that calls the migration code:

```
    namespace :related_products do  
      desc "run any migrations we may have in db/migrate"
      task :migrate => :environment do   
        ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/migrate', ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil )   
    end
```

My console pukes out an error when the call to ActiveRecord::MIgrator.migrate() is made.
rake aborted!
undefined method `info' for nil:NilClass

The migration code itself is pretty simple... and presents me with no clues as to what this missing info class is.

```
    class CreateStores < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up       
        create_table :stores do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.string :access_url
          t.timestamps
        end
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :stores
      end
    end
```

I am a little mystified here and am looking for some clues as to what might be wrong. Thanks!

A simple backtrace shows the offensive line is simply the call to the migration:

```
    rake aborted!
undefined method `info' for nil:NilClass
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:473:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:472:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:472:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:400:in `up'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
/Users/baz/Documents/workspace/rp/Rakefile:26
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: Could we see a backtrace? The relevant line seems not to be in the code provided...

Comment: I added the backtrace I get. line 26 is simply the call to ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue, and the fix was to give ActiveRecord some information on where to output logging info.

I added the following to my Rakefile

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = true
```

-Timmy

Comment: I had the exact some problem (Heroku/Sinatra/AR) and this solution worked perfectly. Thanks!